# Spring and JSTL : How to concatenate string value for items in form binding: <form:options items=?

Tags: spring, binding, jstl

I have Spring form binding and using JSTL.

In my controller:

```
modelAndView.addObject("lookupDataId1", new LookupDataObject(1));
modelAndView.addObject("lookupDataId2", new LookupDataObject(2));
```

In my JSP, I wanted to concatenate the word "lookupDataId" and any Ids to be like "lookupDataId1", "lookupDataId2":

```
<form:select path="myform.value">                               
<form:options items="lookupDataId + ${myLookupId}" itemValue="id.lookupId" itemLabel="id.description" />
</form:select>
```

However I get the following error:

```
1773422 [http-8080-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag - Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
```

Please help me how can I concatenate for value of option's items.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: <c:set var="lookupDataId" value="lookupDataId${myLookupId}"/>                     This displays correctly value of lookupDataId2: ${lookupDataId}          <form:select path="myform.value">                               
<form:options items="${lookupDataId}" itemValue="id.lookupId" itemLabel="id.description" />
</form:select>       but still don't work and same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store your items in a list :

```
List<LookupDataObject> items = new ArrayList<LookupDataObject>();
items.add(new LookupDataObject(1));
items.add(new LookupDataObject(2));
modelAndView.addObject("lookupDataIds", items);
```

and then in the JSP

```
<form:options items="${lookupDataIds}" .../>
```

Comment: I don't think this answesr the question above about concatenation. Here you've corrected the OP's mistake in the way he has put the objects in ModelAndView, but I can't see how your solution is helping in showing a value+id concatenated value for items.